# Translate Woosidebars plugin strings

Tags: plugins, translation

I'm  trying to translate Woosidebars strings in french using PoEdit but my french strings are never shown on the front-end. English strings are always displayed, even when I change the language (And I can see it works since other plugins strings are well translated).

I've created and added a french translation file called 'woosidebars-fr_FR.po' in the 'woosidebars/lang/' folder. This file is compiled without errors (.mo)

If someone had the same issue it would be great to share a solution!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found why this strange thing was happening on my website.

It appears there was a conflict with the WPML String translation module which was already installed and configured to translate widget strings.

`fr_FR.po` file was never called because the WPML plugin was configured to use database translated strings and not `.po`/`.mo` files for widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your files, from `woosidebars-fr_FR.po` to `fr_FR.po`. The same for `.mo` file.

Comment: Hi @tran, it doesn't work. If I look into the code, in _classes/class-woo-sidebars.php_ I can see the plugin tries to load a file called _woosidebars-xx_XX.mo_

Comment: I think you should find a plugin and see how they did. I suggest this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-avatar/. This is a plugin with translation and not many files. Look for the word `load_plugin_textdomain` in the file `user-avatar.php`. Find the difference between your plugins and that plugin. Hope this helps.

Comment: It appears there was a conflict with the WPML String translation module which was already installed and configured to translate widget strings.